# How to use multiple AND statement to check char

Tags: c++, oop

```
while (weather != 'S' || 'R' || 'W') {

        cout << "Invalid input for weather" << endl;
        std::cout << "Please enter today's weather [S]unny, [R]ainy, [W]indy: " << endl;
        cin >> weather;
}
```

If weather is equal to S R or W I want it to continue on with the program but if its not S R or W then i want it to run the while statement. But even if the weather input is S R or W it runs the while statement anyway. Any advice?

Ive tried

```
while ((weather != 'S') || (weather != 'R') || (weather != 'W')) {

        cout << "Invalid input for weather" << endl;
        std::cout << "Please enter today's weather [S]unny, [R]ainy, [W]indy: " << endl;
        cin >> weather;
}
```

but that didn't work either. I even attempted

```
while (weather != 'S') {
     while (weather != 'R') { 
          while (weather != 'W')) {

        cout << "Invalid input for weather" << endl;
        std::cout << "Please enter today's weather [S]unny, [R]ainy, [W]indy: " << endl;
        cin >> weather;
          }
     }
}
```

but to nothing seems to work.

Comment: `||` is not AND, it is OR. `&&` is AND.

Answer (score 0):

You want to execute the while loop if **all** the conditions are true, that means `&&` not `||`

```
while ((weather != 'S') && (weather != 'R') && (weather != 'W')) {
```

Try saying it out loud 'execute the loop if weather does not equal S and weather does not equal R and weather does not equal W'.

Another way to write the same condition is

```
while (!((weather == 'S') || (weather == 'R') || (weather == 'W'))) {
```

Try saying that one out loud 'execute the loop if it is not that case that weather equals S or weather equals R or weather equals W'.

It's very common for beginners to make logical errors where negation is involved. Probably you got the two possibilities above confused and came up with an expression that wasn't equal to either of them.